# issue when compiling ionic app with Phonegap Build: black screen

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ionic-framework

I have just compiled for the first time my Ionic app on Phonegap Build, then I installed the app on my Android device : Samsung Galaxy SII i9100, with Android 4.0.3.

But I get a black screen:

`<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` is empty.

I put the config.xml file in the www folder.

The app works well in my desktop browser.

Can you help me figure this out ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you `ionic serve` your application and then open it on your computer's browser?

Comment: @Keval yes it opens well in my browser.

Comment: Could you use the adb and provide the debug log here? You first need to connect your device to your PC via USB. This command will help you filter out Cordova's errors. `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S)`

Comment: Have you already updated ionic I recently had some splashscreen problems but after updating ionic it finds splashscreens again.

Comment: @Blauharley yes I have the last version. @Keval ok thanks, (I really never do the adb thing), and I see there is `angular.js missing` error. I think my git command ignores the `lib` directory. I am trying again right now...

Comment: @Keval  ok now that I have added the necessary files in www/lib, I get a new error in the logcat : I/CordovaLog(15320): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaLog(15320): file:///android_asset/www/js/services.js: Line 47 : in connectionStatus, isPhoneGap = true
D/CordovaLog(15320): file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js: Line 11560 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
D/CordovaLog(15320): file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer/www/EmailComposer.js: Line 52 : ****************************

Comment: it seems that it is in my service that checks if the device is online. I'm using `navigator.network.connection.type`, in the console it works well, I don't understand what to do....

Comment: Should the config.xml be in the root directory or in the `www/` directory ?

Comment: The config.xml goes into the root directory. And I don't entirely follow your error since I've not seen your code, but check my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Before Cordova 2.3.0, the Connection object existed at:
>   navigator.network.connection.
>
> To match the spec, this was changed to navigator.connection in 2.3.0.
>
> navigator.network.connection still exists, but is now deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future release.

Instead of `navigator.network.connection.type`, it should be `navigator.connection.type`

So, change

```
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```

to

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

Hope this helps. And if it doesn't please edit your question and post your whole log again, if that wasn't the complete log.